# flat list as a result of list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I use list comprehension in such a way that for each element I have 2 resulting values:

```
my_list = [10,20,30]
res_list = [ (x*2, x*3) for x in my_list ]
res_list # [(20, 30), (40, 60), (60, 90)]
```

But I need to have a flatten list, so I have to perform another comprehension:

```
res_list_1 = [yy for xx in res_list for yy in xx]
res_list_1 # [20, 30, 40, 60, 60, 90]
```

Is there any way to avoid this and get flat `res_list` directly on the first comprehension?

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: expected output would be `[20, 30, 40, 60, 60, 90]` - now I have it only after second comprehension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `tuple` at the end:

```
res_list_1 = [item for object in my_list for item in (object*2, object*3)]
```