# How can a Python list be sliced such that a column is moved to being a separate element column?

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list of the following form:

```
[[0, 5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
 [0, 4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2],
 [0, 4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
 [1, 4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
 [1, 5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
 [1, 5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
 [1, 4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3]]
```

I want to slice out the first column and add it as a new element to each row of data (so at each odd position in the list), changing it to the following form:

```
[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2], [0],
 [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2], [0],
 [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2], [0],
 [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2], [1],
 [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2], [1],
 [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4], [1],
 [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3], [1],]
```

How could I do this?

So far, I have extracted the necessary information in the following ways:

```
targets = [element[0] for element in dataset]
features = dataset[1:]
```

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057294/flat-list-as-a-result-of-list-comprehension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain
print list(chain(*[list((element[1:],[element[0]])) for element in a]))
```

Output:

```
[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2], [0], [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2], [0],
 [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2], [0], [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2], [1], 
 [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2], [1], [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4], [1], 
 [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3], [1]]
```

Comment: Instead of unpacking you can use `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([list((element[1:],[element[0]])) for element in l]))`

Answer (score 5):

Try indexing and then get flattened list- i used list comprehension for flattening.

```
>>>l=[[0, 5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
 [0, 4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2],
 [0, 4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
 [1, 4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
 [1, 5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
 [1, 5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
 [1, 4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3]]
>>>[[i[1:],[i[0]]] for i in l]#get sliced list of lists
>>>[[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2], [0]], [[4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2], [0]], [[4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2], [0]], [[4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2], [1]], [[5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2], [1]], [[5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4], [1]], [[4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3], [1]]]
>>>d=[[i[1:],[i[0]]] for i in l]
>>>[item for sublist in d for item in sublist]#flatten list d
>>>[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2], [0], [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2], [0], [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2], [0], [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2], [1], [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2], [1], [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4], [1], [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3], [1]]
```

**Just oneliner alternative**-

```
[item for sublist in [[i[1:],[i[0]]] for i in l] for item in sublist] #Here l is that list
```

Comment: This is close, but you need to flatten the result.

Comment: And how about an explanation?

Answer (score 4):

List comprehensions are nice but can be a bit hard to scan. Loops are still useful, especially when combined with `extend`:

```
res = []
for entry in dataset:
    res.extend([entry[1:], entry[:1]])
```

now:

```
import pprint    
pprint.pprint(res)
```

prints:

```
[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
 [0],
 [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2],
 [0],
 [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
 [0],
 [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
 [1],
 [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
 [1],
 [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
 [1],
 [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
 [1]]
```

Comment: Best answer just because you have not used a list comprehension...    `[r.extend((el[1:],el[:1])) for r in [[]] for el in dataset]; print r`

Comment: @gboffi Nice try. But it does not work in Python 3 because `r` is not defined after the list comprehension. You would need two lines `res = [];
[res.extend([entry[1:], entry[:1]]) for entry in dataset]`. List comprehensions with side effects are not really nice. Typically you want a useful return value.

Comment: Well, I've  learned about the side effects in P2's list comprehensions the hard way... personally I'm very happy of the new behaviour and the code in my comment was just a joke.

Comment: Maybe a candidate for a code-examples-version of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyjokes ;).

Answer (score 2):

Slice each sublist and make a new `list` with an element for each slice:

```
l = [[0, 5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
 [0, 4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2],
 [0, 4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
 [1, 4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
 [1, 5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
 [1, 5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
 [1, 4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3]]
```

```
>>> print(*[item for sub in l for item in (sub[1:], [sub[0]])], sep='\n')
[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]
[0]
[4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2]
[0]
[4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2]
[0]
[4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2]
[1]
[5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2]
[1]
[5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4]
[1]
[4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3]
[1]
```

Comment: Using the print on the list comprehension makes it rather difficult to scan. Using two lines and having the print separated would be easier on the eye. Also, you can use `pprint`.

Answer (score 1):

A Pythonic approach in python 3.X using unpacking iteration and `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> 
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([[j,[i]] for i,*j in A]))
[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2], [0], 
 [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2], [0], 
 [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2], [0], 
 [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2], [1], 
 [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2], [1], 
 [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4], [1], 
 [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3], [1]]
```

Comment: This is Python3-only. The `*j` unpacking does not work in Python 2.